# Uploading CSV file to DynamoDB using Python script

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am trying to upload a CSV file to DynamoDB. For this I have written below Python script:

```
import boto3
import csv

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')


def batch_write(table, rows):
  table = dynamodb.Table(table_name)

  with table.batch_writer() as batch:
    for row in rows:
        batch.put_item(row)

def read_csv(csv_file, list1):
    rows = csv.DictReader(open(csv_file))

    for row in rows:
        list1.append(row)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   table_name = 'Chicago_rest_ass4'
   file_name = 'Food_Inspections.csv'
   items = []

   read_csv(file_name, items)
   status = batch_write(table_name, items)
   if status == 'True':
      print('Data is saved')
   else:
      print('Error while inserting data...')
```

But getting below error:

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the BatchWriteItem operation: One or more parameter values were invalid: An AttributeValue may not contain an empty string

I am unable to identify how `Item=row` is empty? Or what should I do to fix this

Comment: is your csv has null string?

Comment: You can ignore setting a non-key attribute but you cannot explicitly set it to an empty string. After you read the csv, take a look at the items and remove any key-value pairs where value is empty string.

Comment: Actually dynamodb doesn't allow entering empty value to any attribute. Addressed the issue and now it is working. Thanks @SasankMukkamala